# Какой частью речи  является ПУСТЬ?

Tags: морфология

Какой частью речи  является ПУСТЬ в форме повелительного наклонения (пусть придет)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, формообразующая частица. Образует форму повелительного наклонения глагола, частица бы - форму условного.

Answer (score 2):

Пусть- модальная частица

Comment: Спасибо, напомнили)) Только это все-таки формообразующая частица.

Comment: В моем ответе я опиралась на Краткий справочник по современному русскому языку. Авторы Касаткин, Клобуков, Лекант. В данном источнике частицы классифицируются на модальные и амодальные. Среди модальных выделяются модально-волевые, персуазивные, авторизационные, вопросительные, отрицательные. Зачем задавать вопрос, проверяя знания остальных и зная заранее ответ? Вы приняли только тот ответ, который знали сами, и решили, что всё остальное неверно. Несправедливо!